# Child's science fiction book about kids in space with a metal disk and an alien chasing them after it

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, childrens-novel

I recall reading a book in the 5th grade about a boy, a girl and a dog that end up traveling through space with an odd lizard-like alien.  The kids found a piece of metal (a disk) and nailed it to their play "space ship" they have built.  The alien is sort a master of disguise but he does it rather poorly. And he is out to recover the metal disc.

This weird metal gives the little club house/space ship the ability to fly and go into out into the solar system to visit some of the planets. I recall they go to Venus and almost get devoured by some type of creature.  Oddly, the kids and dog have to wear clothespins on their noses to keep from perishing in space as the result of some drug the alien has given them.  It is an odd plot for sure, but it was a cool book for a kid.

Comment: Can you remember when you read this? Was it new at the time? Do we know how the kids got the disk or how it works? Why is the alien after it? Are they flying around for fun or some other reason? You can edit your question if you want to add anything else in.

Comment: I read this when I was about 10 years old, I think ... 57 years ago!  Altdude

Answer (score 12):

This sounds very much like *Rusty's Space Ship* By Evelyn Shipley Lampman, 1957.

Two children, Rusty and Susan, build a play spaceship, which becomes a real spaceship when they get involved with a lizard like alien who visited Earth and now wants to return to his home planet Eopee.

It is mentioned in various previous answers:

- [Kids' book about boys finding a disc from a planet called "Eyopee"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202126/kids-book-about-boys-finding-a-disc-from-a-planet-called-eyopee/202129#202129)
- [60's book about a boy who builds a spaceship from cardboard in garage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214382/60s-book-about-a-boy-who-builds-a-spaceship-from-cardboard-in-garage/214384#214384)
- [Children's novel: three children (plus dog?) travel to the Moon in pretend spaceship turned real](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66578/childrens-novel-three-children-plus-dog-travel-to-the-moon-in-pretend-space/145518#145518)

My answer to this question about navigation in space wonders whether the alien in *Rusty's Space Ship* ever found his home:

[https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/180161/finding-earth-on-a-star-map/180214#180214[1]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/180161/finding-earth-on-a-star-map/180214#180214%5B1%5D)

Comment: THAT'S IT!  Thanks! Altdude

Answer (score 3):

As per [Children's book with a small green alien who has a metal umbrella as a spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177080/), this may be *[Rusty's Spaceship](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11390330-rusty-s-space-ship)* by Evelyn Lampman.

> Rusty bad built the Terra Terror I out of a box and some tin cans, and it was hardly the kind of space ship for a trip to the moon! But, nevertheless, Rusty and Susan found themselves flying through space with a messenger from Eopee and a flying saucer attached to their ship.

Comment: Also shows up at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/145518/23243 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/214384/23243

Comment: Yesssss indeed!  Thanks!  Altdude

Comment: @altdude Don't forget to accept an answer.