# What is the oldest story in which a kid made a spaceship out of junk?

Tags: short-stories, history-of, childrens-novel

What is the oldest story in which a kid made a spaceship out of junk? In the 1960s I read an inspiring English-language children's book that was based on the premise of kids building a spaceship from materials found in a junkyard, but it seems to me that this was a common trope, so I am asking for either a novel or a short story, whichever was published earlier. I was disappointed to find that my community didn't have a junkyard, though my mother was relieved.

Comment: In [The Available Data on the Worp Reaction](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74061) by Lion Miller, "The Mag of F&/SciFi", Sep 1953, we have a challenged kid who proceeds to build, not exactly a spaceship but at least an antigrav machine. _Shortly after reaching his sixth birthday—the time is unfortunately only approximate - Aldous Worp began a series of exploratory trips to the city dump which was located to the rear of the Worp premises... Thus began a project that did not end for nearly twenty years. "No tools"_ Specialists look at it but hit a wall. Worp dismantles it afterwards.

Comment: It's only a slight stretch and the junk trope is intact, so that would be acceptable. Can we push it back farther in time?

Comment: Not applicable because there is no junkyard (although I now consider Captain Future a kid): Captain Future builds a spaceship from zero and assorted junk and with the help of convicts on an asteroid in Edmond Hamilton's 1942 story "The Face of the Deep" ([archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Captain_Future_v05n01_1942_-_Better/page/n11/mode/2up)). There is only calcium that's missing to get this drive running. Now where do you get that? (This is somewhat like Jules Verne's ["L'île Mystérieuse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Island) ... but in Space!)

Comment: Kids build their own spaceshop from odds and ends in _The Wonderful Flight to the Mushroom Planet_, but that's from 1954.

Comment: This is quite a stretch but in Bradbury's 1947 "Zero Hour" the children, guided by alien invaders, build not spaceships but interdimensional (oir interspacial) portals out of "knives and forks and pokers and old stove pipes and can-openers."

Comment: @user14111 Yes, it's a bit of a stretch, though a similar combination of ideas: kids, junk, travel. I've read the Miller and Bradbury stories, but not, so far as I recall, the Cameron novel. Have been wracking my brains over this. The book with the spaceship constructed from junk was not _Miss Pickerill Goes to Mars_,  _The Spaceship under the Apple Tree_, or _Space Cat_, all of which I read as a kid.

Comment: @user14111 In that case, let's stretch again to [Mimsy Were the Borogoves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimsy_Were_the_Borogoves) (Henry Kuttner and Kathleen Moore, 1943), where the kids just warp out of the space-time continuum after the get ahold of a device for accelerated learning from the future.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Not Kathleen but Catherine Lucille, who went by initials C. L. when not writing under a pseudonym like "Lewis Padgett". But yes, "Mimsy . . ." is no more of a stretch than "Zero Hour", and older.

Comment: The kids in _Mimsy_ find a box of toys, not unassembled junk. It's a good story but I'm afraid it's the answer to some other question.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron It's time for you to reread "Mimsy Were the Borogoves". The kids learned advanced science from the box of toys from the future, but then they disappear through a contraption they made out of "rocks, bits of machinery, candle ends, and assorted junk."

Comment: Ah. Memories... can be beautiful, and yet...
Well, that takes it back to 1943.

Comment: Not a great match to your criteria, but Heinlein's Rocket Ship Galileo is from 1947: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Ship_Galileo . Since this was considered "too far out" by publishers, it seems reasonable to say that nothing of the even crazier type you describe was done before 1947.

Comment: I didn't expect that 1940s kids would be so resourceful at building devices that could travel through space, time, and interdimensional portals, or at making spaceships from materials that weren't really junk. I appreciate all of your suggestions and answers. But to be fair, I asked, "What is the oldest story in which a kid made a spaceship out of junk?", not a timeship or dimensionship, and the oldest spaceship so far discovered in SF literature is _The Wonderful Flight to the Mushroom Planet_ (1954), so unless someone finds an earlier example, that's it. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Eleanor Cameron's 1954 novel *[The Wonderful Flight to the Mushroom Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Flight_to_the_Mushroom_Planet)*, two boys build a spaceship out of odds and ends (old pieces of scrap metal and a derelict rowboat) after seeing an ad requesting one in the newspaper.

At the behest of Mr. Bass, the little man who placed the ad, they (and their pet chicken) fly their spaceship to the Mushroom Planet, a small satellite of Earth that only Mr. Bass knows about.

This is the first in a series of books involving these boys, their homemade spaceship, Mr. Bass, and the Mushroom Planet. I recall having an epic fight with my brother over who got to read the last book in the series (*Time and Mr. Bass*) first.

Comment: I can't see how a rowboat could contribute.

Comment: @releseabe As I recall, the curved boat ribs made a perfect framework to give that classic rocket-ship shape.

Comment: ah. i see no other problems then.

Comment: A lot of people were taking wonderful trips to the mushroom planet back then.

Comment: @Adamant That was a decade later.

Comment: @releseabe rowboats are like the duck tape of space exploration

Comment: Perhaps it's the thought that counts

Comment: Found a copy of this book in a local library, and can confirm that it does meet the criteria and is a minor classic. The boat pieces were convenient because they were wood steamed into curves that could act as a frame for the tin sheet and pounded-out tin cans that the boys used for the skin of the spaceship -- which they completed from scratch in three days. A man contributed the fuel and the Mushroom Planet, which wasn't very large, was an invisible satellite only 50,000 miles above the Earth. Alas, I did not read this book in childhood, when I would have loved it.

Comment: I was trying to recall this book, which I read when I was 10 or 11, and that's why I joined scifi SE. Thanks very much for posting the details!

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron there are sequels; not as good as the first, but I liked them as a kid in the 60s.

Answer (score 6):

The scientist Dolph Haertel was a character in several James Blish stories.  In *Welcome to Mars* (1967), serialized as "The Hour Before Earthrise" in 1966, Dolph Haertel is a teenager who discovers antigravity and turns his treehouse into a spaceship to make the first  voyage to Mars.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?32896 [1](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?32896)

I can't help thinking that Blish was inspired to make a more adult and plausible version of stories in children's literature.

I believe that in the early 1960s there was a picture book where cartoon characters, I think Huckleberry Hound and his friends, built a homemade rocket for a moon trip which didn't get very far off the ground.

In *Rusty's Space Ship*, 1957, by Evelyn Shipley Lampman, two kids build a play spaceship out of assorted junk.  But as it happens a piece of metal they find in a junkyard and nail onto the wooden ship is actually a tiny alien spaceship.  The alien, a lizard man named Tripetha or something, shows up to reclaim his spaceship.  (I'm not sure how he fit into a spaceship which was much smaller than him.)  Since his spaceship is attached to the Kid's play spaceship he takes it and them on his search for his homeworld Eopee.

The book is mentioned in a number of questions.

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235351/childs-science-fiction-book-about-kids-in-space-with-a-metal-disk-and-an-alien/235353#235353[2]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235351/childs-science-fiction-book-about-kids-in-space-with-a-metal-disk-and-an-alien/235353#235353%5B2%5D)

[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235351/childs-science-fiction-book-about-kids-in-space-with-a-metal-disk-and-an-alien/235355#235355[3]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235351/childs-science-fiction-book-about-kids-in-space-with-a-metal-disk-and-an-alien/235355#235355%5B3%5D)

So kids build a play spaceship out of assorted stuff, some acquired from a junkyard, and their spaceship actually works, though due to alien technology instead of theirs.

[Added 01-06-2021.  I just noticed that *The Wonderful Flight to the Mushroom Planet* by Eleanor Cameron has a date of 1954 and not 1964.  Thus it was published about 3 years before *Rusty's Space Ship*.]

In Robert heinlein's *Rocket Ship Galileo* (1947), teenage boys convert a rocket airplane into a manned spaceship capable of making a moon landing and return, under the instruction of a brilliant scientist who has invented a new application of atomic energy for space flight.  Obviously none of the characters has millions of dollars to buy expensive equipment, though I doubt where they get anything as cheaply as from a junkyard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Ship_Galileo

I remember an early science fiction story from the 1930s in which an alien crashed on Earth and built or grew a new spaceship out of very common and ordinary materials.  It might have been a novel by Fletcher Pratt, such as *Invaders from Rigel*
(1931,1960)

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7453

Or maybe *Alien Planet* (1962).

Surprisingly, I couldn't find a trope about kids building a spaceship out of junkyard materials at TV Tropes.

Comment: The isfdb link for Haertel - which I had to upvote the minute I saw a reference to Haertel - comes up with only a "Bad Argument". The only time I have encountered this on a link to ISFDB.
Findable, I'm sure, but might want to edit the link.

Anything related to Blish's "Common Time" is a treasure to me!

Comment: @Occam Shave  I replaced the link and tested it and it worked.  But who knows if it will still work by the time you try it again.  And right after I wrote this comment I tested the ling again and got "Bad Argument".

Comment: @Occam Shave    I tried it agin and I got "Bad Argument".  I corrected it again and it worked  at 12:16 AM Jan. 6 , 2021, but I don't know if will still work when you try it.  I tried it again at 12:18 AM and it said "Bad Argument".  It seems like I can't bet to link to work for more than a minute or two.

Comment: @Occam Shave  I tried my other links in my answer and only the links to other questions here work.

Comment: All interesting and one quite early (1947). The list gets longer!

Comment: The [_Explorers_](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Explorers) TV Tropes page has some likely tropes.